# Do you use static or kinetic friction when calculating this problem?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction

You are given mass and initial velocity of a vehicle and told that you need to stop. You are given kinetic and static friction and asked to find the minimum distance. Would you use kinetic friction or static friction in order to find the acceleration?

Comment: Does it have ABS?

Answer (score 1):

If the wheel still has traction, you use static friction.

Although the vehicle is still moving, the tire is not sliding across the ground.